# DLIB shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat documentation?

Tags: c++, face-detection, dlib

I'm wondering if there is any documentation about the `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat`NOT in terms about "how to compile" or "how to use" more like how it is set up?, what are the training data (what kind of images, how many, ...)?, who did it? and stuff like this.

I was just able to find a lot code samples that are using the file more or less without questioning :D

I'm using dlib as stated in the headline, but it may be the case that its working with other library's as well?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's trained on the iBUG 300W dataset.  There is some additional discussion about it on the dlib blog post: http://blog.dlib.net/2014/08/real-time-face-pose-estimation.html

Also, the primary dlib author (me) made it.